# duplicate key value violates unique constraint "_block_number_txid_pkey"

Tags: eosjs

I get this error when I run demux postgres the first time:

```
Key (block_number)=(1) already exists
```

The code abruptly stops. How do I fix this?

````
dataType:undefined
detail:"Key (block_number)=(1) already exists."
file:"nbtinsert.c"
hint:undefined
internalPosition:undefined
internalQuery:undefined
length:228
line:"535"
message:"duplicate key value violates unique constraint "_block_number_txid_pkey""
name:"error"
position:undefined
routine:"_bt_check_unique"```
````

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's a postgres-exception forwarded via demux.

The database-record probably already exists in your database - the key already exists, which is why the exception is throwing.

Try to clear the database before each application-start or start your application from a different block (maybe last processed + 1 is a good choice).

```
const init = async () => {
  const massiveInstance = await massive(dbConfig);
  const actionHandler = new MassiveActionHandler(
    handlerVersions,
    massiveInstance,
    migrationSequences,
    {
      validateBlockHashes: false,
      dbSchema: dbConfig.schema
    }
  );

  const dfuseActionReader = new DfuseActionReader({
    startAtBlock: 50575524,
    onlyIrreversible: true,
    dfuseApiKey: process.env.DFUSE_API_KEY as string,
    query: "account:kmealowner12",
    network: "kylin"
  })
  const actionWatcher = new BaseActionWatcher(dfuseActionReader, 
    actionHandler, {
    logLevel: "trace"
  })
  actionWatcher.watch(true)
}
```

i am using the newly created dfuseActionReader

Comment: tried clearing the database. start block is set to 50575524. don't understand why i get  (block_number)=(1)

Comment: can you post some code @Bhaskar? How do you inititalize/start demux?